# How to I get array of Result Using facebook SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried the code below to get My id details Using graph API:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook ([
'app_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
'app_secret' => 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
]);


$fbApp = new Facebook\FacebookApp('{APP_ID HERE}', '{SECRET HERE}');


$request = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($fbApp, '{ACCESS TOKEN HERE}', 'GET', '/me?fields=id,name,posts{likes}');
$arr = $fb->getClient();


print_r($arr);
try {

$response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
When Graph returns an error
echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
 exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
When validation fails or other local issues
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
echo 'User name: ' . $graphNode['name'];
```

However, I got following Result:

> Facebook\FacebookClient Object ( [enableBetaMode:protected] => [httpClientHandler:protected] => Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient Object ( [curlErrorMessage:protected] => [curlErrorCode:protected] => 0 [rawResponse:protected] => [facebookCurl:protected] => Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl Object ( [curl:protected] => ) ) )

I am new to this concept, I didn't understand this Error. How do I get the array of values for my id?

I have used facebook SDK5

Comment: Documentation has example snippets on how to properly use GraphNode, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphNode/5.0.0

Comment: Btw., doing it this way is rather cumbersome. I suggest you have a look at the basic examples in the documentation, such as https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile